# How to escape %%

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a very simple batch script which echos onto another batch file in order to keep things organised. Whilst doing this, I noticed that if I did something like:

```
@echo if %cd%==C:\Users\whoever\Desktop msg * success
```

then it would echo the current directory, since I put in "%cd%". How would I escape this so that it instead echos %cd%, rather then: `C:\Users\whoever\desktop\file`

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I believe you should just use %% to escape a single % to prevent it from being interpreted.

Comment: @codechurn Except if the `%%` percents are around an existing variable name. Try `echo "%%cd%%"` to see why the workarounds in the answer I posted are necessary in those cases.

Comment: @dxiv  the problem occurs only at the command line, in batch files the doubling is enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

escaping can be a bit un-intuitive.

within batchfiles, `%` are escaped with another `%`: `echo %%cd%%`

on command line you can't really escape them but "fake-escaping" them with a caret: `echo ^%cd^%` does the trick, because `cmd` shows `%varName%`, if `varname` isn't defined, so trying to show the non-defined variable `cd^` shows `%cd%` instead (the parser swallows the caret). The starting caret is not really needed, but makes the "fake-escaping" more consistent.

```
C:>@echo if ^%cd^%==C:\Users\whoever\Desktop msg * success
if %cd%==C:\Users\whoever\Desktop msg * success
C:>type t.bat
@echo if %%cd%%==C:\Users\whoever\Desktop msg * success   
C:>t
if %cd%==C:\Users\whoever\Desktop msg * success
C:>
```

Comment: In reality it can't be escaped on the command line. The carets don't escape the percent signs, the only creates an undefined variable name, like 'cd^'

Comment: @jeb: indeed... (nice to know). Nevertheless - it works like intended (until the variable gets defined (unlikely - who would use a caret as part of a variable name? (rhetorical question...)))

Comment: Thank you so much! This has helped a ton!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an elegant one-liner, but the following will work:

```
@echo off
set "random=cd"
echo %%%random%%% = "%cd%"
set "random="
```

Output:

```
%cd% = "C:\Users\whoever\desktop\file"
```

Note that the temporary variable does *not* need to be named `random`, only since it's a reserved name chances are lower that it would overwrite some other defined variable.

---

**[ EDIT ]** An alternative, in case the construct is used repeatedly, would be the following (at the expense of using a dedicated environment variable `pct`):

```
@echo off
set "pct=%%"
echo %pct%cd%pct% = "%cd%"
```

Comment: Using reserved names is a bad idea, as you change the *normal* behaviour, in this case the random functionallity doesn't work anymore. BTW the extra variable isn't necessary here. Your *pct * usage is only necessary at the command-line, but there it's safer than the caret solution

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate all the help!

Comment: @jeb `in this case the random functionallity doesn't work anymore` It's only used temporarily, and the posted example undefines it on the very next line `set "random="` precisely for the reason you mention.